# How can I optimize my query to run faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

User table has

```
id, email, password, gender, dob
```

etc. Gender is default null. I have another table `user_gender` which has `first_name` and `gender`. My sql query is getting the user from `User` and picking the gender from `User_Gender` based on `first_name`. The user table is huge with somewhere around 300,000+ rows. I am running the below mentioned query, but it is taking too much time. How do I optimize this query?-

```
select 
   count(*) 
from user u 
left outer join user_gender ug on ug.name = 
  case when locate(' ', u.name) > 0 then
     substring(u.name, 1,locate(' ', u.name))
  else
     u.name 
  end 
where 
  ug.gender != 'mf' and u.gender is null
```

Comment: 1st thought: explain plan.... 2nd thought: Case when... in join? It's no wonder this takes long to run...

Comment: I assume all your users have a gender and a firstname so why are they in a seperate table? - Plus you should join on a primary / foriegn key so the join on name is bad

Comment: users have name (not  separate column for first and last name).

Comment: there should be seperate columns to amke searching more efficent

Comment: Other from the already detected problems, show your indexes. That could also help to detect possible performance issues.

Comment: There is no way this query can use indices

Comment: Before you optimize this query you must really rethink your data structure.  300,000 is not a huge table.  And where is u.name coming from?

Comment: You are correct @Esailija but once the query is rewritten indexes are important.

Comment: @Yaroslav but you can't really rewrite this query well without changing the  schema to something more sensible.

Comment: @Yaroslav I'd say: _only after_ the restructuring are indexes important. This is not indexable, and is generally bad in this form.

Comment: Correct. There is lot of work to do, and indexes should be also one thing to look. Schema and query can be ok, if the indexes are incorrectly configured there could be problems too. From the detected issues here I'm guessing that indexes are also not taken care of too.

Comment: `join user_gender ug on ug.name = CASE...` will use an index on `ug.name` if it exists, but you will pull all records which have `u.gender is null` (I'm guessing you have a lot of those).

Answer (score 6):

**First** I advise a complete restructuring. 300000 rows are starting to hit the "medium data set" size...

- [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) tables properly

  - don't use columns that store more than one separate values - especially the name column is a fine example what not to d. Let that be two columns: first_name and last_name.
  - DavidB mentioned the gender separation. This is total nonsense. At least, everyone has a Gender... Is unknown, it could always be `NULL`...
- use (preferably numeric!!) IDs, instead of using data fields (especiallz those like names)

  - this way, if the name is changed (that can happen IRL), you have to update only one row...
  - two people might even have completely the same name...

**Secondly** after the restructuring, you'll have to apply indexes, and [check your queries' execution plans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) to be sure to optimize them appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Working on the design of these two tables first will help you better on solving your performance problem.
The problem for the performance occurs on your join clause:

> case when locate(' ', u.name)>0 then substring(u.name, 1,locate(' ',
>   u.name)) else u.name end

Use a primary key (user_id) for your User table and have this on your user_gender table and join accordingly.

OR

Since perhaps you are using a legacy database design and cannot add or use user_id fields, you may use a temporary first_name field and fill it by using your join clause

```
update users u set u.first_name = case when locate(' ', u.name)>0 
then substring(u.name, 1,locate(' ',> u.name)) else u.name end
```

After this you may rewrite your query as

```
select count(*) from user u left outer join user_gender ug 
on ug.name=u.first_name 
where ug.gender != 'mf' and u.gender is null
```

This will help your query run faster but I would propose the first solution, adding/using primary keys anyway.

Comment: +1 . . . I think this is the more practical solution.  And you at least hint at what the actual performance problem is.

Comment: both the tables user and user_gender are already having id as primary keys. And the user_gender simply contains some known names and their gender. This table is very small one. But the User table is a huge one.

Comment: @NihalSharma the problem is that you do not have a user_id key in your user_gender table (known as foreign key). If it had, this would an easy join. So the second approach (generating a first_name from name field of user table) will help you better

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I note is that the query is not written correctly.  Or, at least, it is not doing what you intend.  The `!=` in the `where` clause is "undoing" the left outer join.  I think you want that in the `on` clause.

With an index on `user_gender(firstname, gender)`, I think this version should run pretty quickly:

```
select count(*) 
from (select u.*,
             (case when locate(' ', u.name) > 0 then substring(u.name, 1,locate(' ', u.name))
                   else u.name
              end) as FirstName
      from user u
     ) u
where not exists (select 1 from user_gender ug where ug.name = u.FirstName and ug.gender <> 'mf')
```

It should can the user table, calculate the first name, and check in the index to see if there is a gender.